# Changing value of a select2 in IE 11 causing errors

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-select2

I have the following function to empty values of a select 2, and it is not working in IE 11. It is working in Chrome. Any suggestions?

```
function EmptyValueForSelect2(SelectId) {
$("#"+SelectId).val("").trigger("change");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: did you resolve it ?